# What is the convention or syntax on how to write a function that takes in a set and returns a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we had a set $k$ of some type $t$ (as in the type of the contents) and we wish to describe a function $f$ that takes in any such $k$ and returns a result $k'$. What would be the convention we use to write the expression of such a function (as in $f(k) = blank$)?

I know the basic "operations" such as set builder notation, union, negation, and intersection. Are there any other conventions used that would be considered fundamental to this idea?

In particular I am looking for (operators) that do the following:

Filter every elemt that meets a condition

Map some function to every element and return the result

Apply some commutative and associative operation to every element and return the single result

Comment: This sounds a lot like descriptions of things in Lisp-style programming languages.  I have created a multi-valued function before, using the convention $f:\Bbb Z^+\mapsto \mathcal P(\Bbb Z^+)$, which basically says that $f$ is a function from the positive integers to the subsets of the positive integers.  Is this similar to what you’re looking for?

Comment: The question in the first paragraph is very different from what you are looking for in the rest of the question. The answer to the first paragraph is: If $t$ is a set, then $k$ is an element of its power set (denoted $\mathcal P(t)$ or $2^t$), and $f$ is a function $f:2^t\to2^t$.

Comment: When we write "a function $f~:~A\to B$" this implies that elements of $A$ are used as inputs for $f$ and elements of $B$ are used as outputs of $f$, i.e. $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain.  *This same notation is used even in the case that the elements IN $A$ and $B$ are sets themselves!*

Comment: Do you have an example you can articulate?  It would help to have something tangible that can be molded into symbolic language.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{F}=\{A\subseteq \Bbb R~:~|A|<\infty\}$ be the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb R$.  One could define such functions as $sum~:~\mathcal{F}\to\Bbb R,~~sum(A)=\sum\limits_{a\in A}a$ and $prod~:~\mathcal{F}\to\Bbb R,~~prod(A)=\prod\limits_{a\in A}a$ which takes input of a finite set of reals and outputs their sum or product respectively.  One could also define such things as $sumlike~:~\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{P(F)},~~sumlike(A)=\{B\in\mathcal{F}~:~\sum\limits_{a\in A}a=\sum\limits_{b\in B}b\}$ which takes a finite set as input and outputs a set of finite sets with the same sum.

Comment: This of course changes based on what it is you are wishing your function to do.  So long as you can describe it with words without ambiguity, that is fine enough.  Although math has been around for quite some time, clearly its impossible for every symbol that could possibly be useful at some point in time to have been invented.  As such, in those cases just use words or invent a new symbol, making sure you define it for your readers in each publication in which it appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, it strongly depends on your foundational system. If you are working in ZFC, then you can construct any function on any domain (a set) as long as you specify a unique output for each input. It does **not** have to be an expression of the sort you are talking about. Those are sometimes called terms and in fact cannot be formed in pure ZFC itself, but can be formed in conservative extensions of ZFC. For example the map $( x,y \mapsto \{x,y\} )$ is not a function in ZFC but can be used anywhere in a definition because ZFC guarantees the existence of such a set with the expected properties. Same for $( x,y \mapsto x \cup y )$. In general foundational systems these are called term-forming operations. In first-order logic they are called definable-maps over ZFC (but they are not functions in ZFC).

There are not many commonly used term-forming operations for sets and functions/relations, but here are some:

> $\varnothing , S \cap T , S \cup T , S \smallsetminus T , S Δ T , \bigcap S , \bigcup S , \{x\} , Dom(f) , Ran(f) , Im_f(S) , f \restriction S , f \circ g , f^{-1}$

And obviously for real analysis we have interval notation as well among other things.

Anyway if you need an uncommon set operation frequently, just **define** it clearly before using it. Otherwise stick to set-builder notation, which itself can be considered a term-forming operation.